# Is the CloudBees Jenkins SaaS PCI Compliant?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am looking for a hosted Jenkins solution that is PCI Compliant, Does CloudBees offer this?

Comment: I think this question requires clarification.
It is PCI Compliance with regards to how CloudBees accepts credit card payments for itself.

Or it is PCI Compliance with regards to hosted applications, ex: I have a business and want to accept CC payments, can I host an APP on CloudBees that receives this information (which requires PCI Compliance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for payment for the Jenkins SaaS - CloudBees is PCI compliant (ie how we handle your CC) - assuming that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees will know the answer; ask them.